# Creating Dynamic Links in an Excel Calendar

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

I've a macro that creates a calendar, based on the current day of the month, and it outputs a typical calendar format.

```
Sub Calendar()

    Dim cDater, endDater, tempDater As Date
    Dim wDay As Variant
    Dim i, ColNum, dInMonth, cDayNum, dRange, rNum As Integer

    cDater = Date 'NORMAL
    'cDater = DateValue("11/24/2019") 'TESTING
    dRange = 30
    dInMonth = Day(DateSerial(Year(cDater), Month(cDater) + 1, 1) - 1)
    endDater = cDater + (dRange - 1)
    rNum = 4

    With Sheets("Calendar")
        .Range("B4:H9").Clear
        .Range("B4:H9").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .Range("B4:H9").VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        For i = 0 To (dRange - 1) 'NORMAL
        'For i = 0 To 3 'TESTING
            tempDater = cDater + i
            cDayNum = Day(tempDater)
            ColNum = (Weekday(tempDater, vbSunday) Mod 8) + 1
            .Cells(rNum, ColNum).Select
            .Cells(rNum, ColNum).Value = cDayNum
            .Cells(rNum, ColNum).NumberFormat = "mm/dd"
            If ColNum = 8 Then rNum = rNum + 1
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

After the calendar is produced, is there a way to create a dynamic link from each of the cells to get information for those specific dates?

For example, if I click on the cell, I want Excel to automatically build a list of things happening on that day. If there are X events in a day for Y people, I'd like the output to look something like this:

**Main Group: 10**

*Person A: 2*

*Person B: 3*

*Person C: 5*

I was thinking it could be similar to a pivot table, in a way, but I'm not sure of how to go about setting all that up with dynamic links and/or VBA.

Comment: Update: I've tried to use the following code as a tester to start, but Excel won't let me step through it. See below:

`Sub tester(ByVal targCel As Range)

    Dim dateSel As Variant

  
    Sheets("Calendar").Activate
    dateSel = ActiveCell.Value
    
    If Selection.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B4:H8")) Is Nothing Then
            Run "Dash_Builder"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function Dash_Builder(dateSel As Variant)

MsgBox "What it do"

End Function`


Any ideas on why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Also - Apparently return characters don't work in comments for me.

Fail.

Comment: Scratch that. I figured it out myself. I had to switch the options to included the SelectionChange feature rather than just general / normal in the overall workbook excel.